# Express the following in terms of elementary functions, without integrals or series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(−1)^nx^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Not sure how to proceed.

Do I play with the algebra, and knowing the fact that $\frac{1}x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty$ ?

Comment: I fixed the latex in the title; the actual summation in the text looks as if something is missing. In the title, was the $n+1$ also supposed to be in the denominator?

Comment: Yup, I fixed it just now. Title is now corrected - thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: Call this expression $f(x)$, and assume for the moment that it's a nice function. Then what's its derivative?

Comment: Hint: what is $\dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: If the summation starts from 0, the answer is $\pm\infty$ for $x\ne 0$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mathsf{No\ Integrals\ !!!}}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{x^{n + 1} \over n\pars{n + 1}} & =
x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n} -
x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n + 1} =
x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n} -
x\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n - 1} \over n}
\\[5mm] & =
x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n} +
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n} =
x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n} + x +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n}
\\[5mm] & = 
\pars{x + 1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n} + x =
\bbx{x - \pars{x + 1}\ln\pars{1 + x}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a typo in $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(−1)^nx^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$$
because the first term at $n=0$ would be infinite.

Supposing that the correct series is :
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(−1)^nx^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(−1)^nx^{n}}{n}=-\ln(1+x)$$
$$f(x)=-\int\ln(1+x)dx=-(1+x)\ln(1+x)+x+C$$
$f(0)=0\quad\to\quad C=0$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(−1)^nx^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=-(1+x)\ln(1+x)+x$$
In the result there is no integral and no series as requested.

Comment: Thank you for the remark.  The error is corrected.